# How To Divide Two Values From Different Tables in Select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I need to divide two tables, `nr1` and `nr2` like shown below

```
SELECT COUNT(candidate.id) as nr1
FROM candidate
WHERE candidate.id=2



select count (candidate.id) as nr2
from candidate 
where candidate.id=2 or candidate.id = 3;

select nr1/nr2 from nr1, nr2;
```

The problem is they don't existe outside the `select` query.

Comment: What is your **RDBMS**? `oracle-sqldeveloper` is a client tool, not a **Database**. So please tag your database vendor appropriately.

Comment: I don't know the school's database vendor.

Comment: You mean you don't know what database you are on? How about executing `SELECT banner FROM v$version WHERE ROWNUM = 1`

Comment: I'm in school's database. I don't know the school's database vendor.

Comment: BANNER                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Understand, **database version** is a pre-requisite for database specific questions. From next time, please make sure you mention these details in your question. And also add appropriate tags. **Thomas Kyte** has a blog about [**How to ask questions**](http://tkyte.blogspot.in/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in single query. `Aggregate` the data *conditionally* in `SELECT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN id = 2  THEN 1 END) 
       / COUNT(CASE WHEN id = 2 || id = 3 THEN 1 END) 
FROM candidate
```

Comment: @DanielaMaia Glad you got your answer. Just remember include a validation to avoid `DIV 0` error as you can see in my answer.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I think conditional case is support for most db. The only part mine may have issue is with CTE where for example mySql doesnt support.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I am not at all pointing to the technicalities in the answers(I upvoted both your answers), I am just curious to know from your both(you and Mahesh) how did you guys interpret that `oracle sql developer` means an `oracle database`?

Comment: @LalitKumarB It's simply a guess. Still seeing the syntax, I tried one similar to it.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Perhaps I am more user friendly, than policy follower. :)

Comment: LOL :-) OP just commented on the question. He is not aware of the **RDBMS** product and the version.

Answer (score 4):

In oracle you can create a cte.

```
With table1 as ( 
      SELECT COUNT(candidate.id) as nr1
      FROM candidate
      WHERE candidate.id=2
), 
table2 as (
     select count (candidate.id) as nr2
     from candidate 
     where candidate.id=2 or candidate.id = 3
)
SELECT table1.nr1 / table2.nr2
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2
```

But a simple way should be using conditional `SUM` also you have to validate for div 0 cases.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT         
       SUM(CASE WHEN candidate.id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nr1,          
       SUM(CASE WHEN candidate.id IN (2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nr2
  FROM candidate
)
SELECT (CASE WHEN nr2 > 0 THEN nr1 / nr2 END) as result
FROM cte
```

Comment: @Burc yes, but I also want to show why his version didnt work.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Tag say oracle developer

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza **NO**. The tag is **`oracle-sqldeveloper`** which is a **client tool** capable to connect to **multiple databases**. It doesn't mean that OP is on **Oracle database**.

Comment: This looks like it would work, but I'm getting syntax errors that I don't know how to correct. The first solution is more "readeable" or "understandeable".

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL developer.

Comment: @DanielaMaia Was an extra `)` in first solution and one missed on second one. Is fixed now.  Please try again. Second solution just create a derivated table, so you can use those value later

Comment: It says table1 is disconnect from rest of join graph, but it gives the right answer.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza OP just commented on the question, he is not aware of the database vendor :-)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza also added this to `SELECT table1.nr1 / NULLIF(table2.nr2, 0)` to avoid dividing by 0.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Really? You looks kind obsessed now. She already solve her issue and you keep pushing?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I wonder how you know the gender of OP as you said "she"? Just kidding... OP has replied to my comments, OP is on `Oracle 12.1`. And I am just helping, don't you think knowing OP's database version is **pre-requisite**?

Comment: @LalitKumarB For something like date or string yes. But not always. And certainly wouldnt start a witch hunt for it. And I saw the picture :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza haha, I saw the movie too(I kinda like Vin Diesel). Anyway, coming to the point, the only reason I get sensitive with RDBMS vendor is especially with DATE, as it is much different in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using conditional aggreation:

```
select (sum(case when c.id = 2 then 1.0 else 0 end) /
        sum(case when c.id in (2, 3) then 1.0 else 0 end)
       ) 
from candidate;
```

Comment: Is there any difference between use conditional `SUM` vs `COUNT`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza in this scenario, we can ignore the `ELSE` part, because `COUNT()` ignores `NULL`. But agreed adding else is definitely readable.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar . . . I have a strong preference for `sum()` because I think it is easy to make a mistake with `count()` (typically by including an `else 0` type of construct).